# How can I tell if there is new data on a pipe?

Tags: c++, winapi, pipe, named-pipes

I'm working on Windows, and I'm trying to learn pipes, and how they work.

One thing I haven't found is how can I tell if there is new data on a pipe (from the child/receiver end of the pipe?

The usual method is to have a thread which reads the data, and sends it to be processed:

```
void GetDataThread()
{
    while(notDone)
    {
        BOOL result = ReadFile (pipe_handle, buffer, buffer_size, &bytes_read, NULL);
        if (result) DoSomethingWithTheData(buffer, bytes_read);
        else Fail();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the ReadFile() function waits for data, and then it reads it. Is there a method of telling if there is new data, without actually waiting for new data, like this:

```
void GetDataThread()
{
    while(notDone)
    {
        BOOL result = IsThereNewData (pipe_handle);
        if (result) {
             result = ReadFile (pipe_handle, buffer, buffer_size, &bytes_read, NULL);
             if (result) DoSomethingWithTheData(buffer, bytes_read);
             else Fail();
        }

        DoSomethingInterestingInsteadOfHangingTheThreadSinceWeHaveLimitedNumberOfThreads();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow... I really _really_ hope you do **not** have a function called `DoSomethingInterestingInsteadOfHangingTheThreadSinceWeHaveLimitedNumberOfThreads`.....

Comment: @Neal No, I actually wrote the entire code on this website.

Comment: I didn't copy from an existing project, I wrote it just for this question. And no, I would never under any circumstance use such a long function name. I usually use comments for such details.

Comment: You should read the Windows API documentation. Most of the times, the answer is right there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365779%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for... but how was I suppose to know that the function is called PeekNamedPipe, I didn't even think of this name. Searching on the internet, I couldn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: You can first search "named pipe windows". The first result is this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. Then you click on "named pipe operations" and you're there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`PeekNamedPipe()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365779%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
DWORD total_available_bytes;
if (FALSE == PeekNamedPipe(pipe_handle,
                           0,
                           0,
                           0,
                           &total_available_bytes,
                           0))
{
    // Handle failure.
}
else if (total_available_bytes > 0)
{
    // Read data from pipe ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way is to use IPC synchronization primitives such as events ([CreateEvent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). In case of  interprocess communication with complex logic -- you should put your attention at them too.

Comment: I don't need very complex communication. For now, I want to create a debugging system using pipes, and mostly strings will be passed around.