# Monitor status of stdin when its a pipe on windows

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio

For my sins, I needed to write an application that "shims" itself between 2 other applications, where those applications communicate via CONSOLE I/O. (Parent sets up anonymous pipes to send commands and read replies.) On Windows.

Courtesy of a LOT of Google-Fu, I have it working. I now have an executable that I make into a middleman by renaming the original child and copying the "shim" over. It executes the renamed program and copies all console I/O to a set of log files.

Unfortunately, it is a massive CPU hog because it has to use PeekPipe() to find out if there is a command on the stdin pipe (to log and relay it to the "real" worker process) or one on the actual worker process' stdout pipe (to relay that back to the parent).

Is there some way I can make this a lot more CPU friendly? Because this will peg a core, and the parent eclipse session actually runs at least 4 of these things. Thank-heaven for quad core + Hyper threading, but this is evil and I'd like to do this somewhat right. (Why cant I just have a real-working select() call?)

```
    // waitobjects[0]= g_hChildStd_IN_Rd; 
    // waitobjects[1]= g_hOurStd_IN;

    if (is_pipe)
    {
        // this is where the hard part happens.
        TCHAR tempstring[1024];

        CreateChildProcess(cmdbuff);

        while (1) {
            DWORD bytestoread;
            DWORD bytesread;
            DWORD byteswritten;
            DWORD exitcode;
            if (GetExitCodeProcess(piProcInfo.hProcess,&exitcode) == 0) 
            {
                ErrorExit(TEXT("Child ccbe status check"));
            }
            else
            {
                if (exitcode != STILL_ACTIVE) {
                    swprintf(tempstring,L"Child process exited with status code %d\n",exitcode);
                    OutputDebugString(tempstring);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    // swprintf(tempstring,L"Child process still active, status code %d\n",exitcode);
                    // OutputDebugString(tempstring);
                }
            }
            // dummydw = WaitForMultipleObjects(2,waitobjects,FALSE,100);
            // swprintf(tempstring,L"Wait completed. %d objects\n",dummydw);
            // OutputDebugString(tempstring);
            if (PeekNamedPipe(g_hOurStd_IN,0,0,0,&bytestoread,0) == 0) // Failed.
            {
                DWORD errcode = GetLastError();
                if (errcode != ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE) 
                {
                    ErrorExit(TEXT("PeekNamedPipe (stdin)"));
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (bytestoread > 0) {
                // read from parent
                ReadFile(g_hOurStd_IN,&iobuff,sizeof(iobuff),&bytesread,NULL);
                // Send to child
                WriteFile(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr,&iobuff,bytesread,&byteswritten,NULL);
                // Write copy to a log file
                swprintf(tempstring,L"%d bytes read from stdin %d bytes written to child\n",bytesread,byteswritten);
                OutputDebugString(tempstring);
                swprintf(tempstring,L">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\n");
                WriteFile(g_hOurLog,tempstring,34,&byteswritten,NULL);
                WriteFile(g_hOurLog,&iobuff,bytesread,&byteswritten,NULL);
            }
            // Sleep(50);
            if (PeekNamedPipe(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd,0,0,0,&bytestoread,0) == 0) // Failed.
            {
                DWORD errcode = GetLastError();
                if (errcode != ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE) 
                {
                    ErrorExit(TEXT("PeekNamedPipe (child)"));
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (bytestoread > 0) {
                // read from child
                ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd,&iobuff,sizeof(iobuff),&bytesread,NULL);
                // Send to parent
                WriteFile(g_hOurStd_OUT,&iobuff,bytesread,&byteswritten,NULL);
                // Write copy to a log file
                swprintf(tempstring,L"%d bytes read from child %d bytes written to stdout\n",bytesread,byteswritten);
                OutputDebugString(tempstring);
                WriteFile(g_hOurLog,&iobuff,bytesread,&byteswritten,NULL);
            }
            // Sleep(50);
            // if (GetExitCodeProcess(piProcInfo.hProcess,&dummydw) != STILL_ACTIVE) break;
        }
    }
```

The commented-out section with WaitForMultipleObjects() was an initial attempt, but it failed miserably.

I used this URL to get the child process started with redirected I/O: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output

And this link told me how to poll a pipe: [How can I tell if there is new data on a pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396870/how-can-i-tell-if-there-is-new-data-on-a-pipe)

I just want to have this "shim" pause when there is no pending I/O. But since I can't assume how much data is going in either direction, it's a little challenging. It also looks like there is some sort of command queueing, so I can't block while waiting for the child process to respond.

If I can get an "event" when there's data in the pipe that would be great.

Comment: Can you not just use a couple threads, one for each direction?

Comment: Well, aside from needing to keep it simple, it also turns out that the parent child process can separately terminate, so i wind up needing more threads to keep track of the parent and child processes.

Comment: Also, going multithreaded is glorious overkill for this usecase. I'm trying to diagnose a problem in one system, I don't want to get bogged down debugging a multithreaded shim application.